# In this way i am storing my app tasks, but displays the last task?

Tags: android, for-loop, sharedpreferences

I have to store and display some tasks using shared preferences.
But i can't , so share some help to make this as simple.

```
task_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
                {
                    String prefs_name = null;
                    SharedPreferences remain= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefs_name,0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor taskedit=remain.edit();
                    taskedit.putString("taskname",edit_task.getText().toString() );
                    taskedit.putString("taskdate", edit_date.getText().toString());
                    taskedit.putString("tasktime", edit_time.getText().toString());
                    taskedit.apply();
                }


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent ret_view=new Intent(Add.this,View_listen.class);
                startActivity(ret_view);
            }
        });
```

The first time i saw three tasks, but after that it only shows only the last added task.

```
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String prefs_name = null;
    SharedPreferences remain= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefs_name,0);
    String viewtask=remain.getString("taskname", "");
    String viewdate=remain.getString("taskdate", "");
    String viewtime=remain.getString("tasktime", "");   
   tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(viewtask).append(" ").append(viewdate).append(" ").append(viewtime));
```

I just confusing and i tried, but i can't retrieve the tasks..

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as for storing all values as key-value pairs in  SharedPreferences :

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
 {
       String prefs_name = null;
       SharedPreferences remain= 
                   getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefs_name,0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor taskedit=remain.edit();
       taskedit.putString("taskname"+i,edit_task.getText().toString() );
       taskedit.putString("taskdate"+i, edit_date.getText().toString());
       taskedit.putString("tasktime"+i, edit_time.getText().toString());
       taskedit.commit();
  }
```

Now you can access your values using taskname0,taskdate0,tasktime0,....

and retrieve as :

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
String viewtask="",viewdate="",viewtime="";
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
  {

     String prefs_name = null;
     SharedPreferences remain= 
            getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefs_name,0);
     if(i==0)
      viewtask+=remain.getString("taskname", "");
     else
      viewtask+=" "+remain.getString("taskname"+i, "");
      viewdate+=" "+remain.getString("taskdate"+i, "");
      viewtime+=" "+remain.getString("tasktime"+i, "");   
  }
 tv.setText(viewtask+" "+viewdate +" "+viewtime);
```

**NOTE :** if you have large amount of data then create an small SQLite database for storing schedule instead of Sharedpreferences. you can see these tutorials for how we create Sqlite database in Android:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: post your relevant code where you are fetching values from SharedPreferences

Comment: after trying if still issue is not solved then comment me i will try to help u